# Map array sections to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I am trying to take an array and split it into sections of length 4 then push these sections into a new array. I wrote small script to solve it here but I am curious as to how other people would solve this. Is there a better way than what I'm doing?

```
var test = ['test0', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7' ];

var splitTest = test.map(function(value, index) {
    if (index % 4 === 0) {
          return ([test[index], test[index + 1], test[index + 2], test[index+3]]);
    }
}).filter(function(value) {
    return typeof value != 'undefined';
});
```

Here is a jsbin of my code:  https://jsbin.com/zubavivoto/edit?js,console

Input

```
["test0", "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]
```

Output

```
[["test0", "test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test4", "test5", "test6", "test7"]]
```

Comment: Lodash has [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs#chunk) as a method, if you weren't aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like @JosephYoung's approach but if you wanted to continue using a functional approach, you could use `reduce`.

```
var test = ['test0', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'test7' ];
var splitTest = test.reduce(function(prev, current, index) {
  if (index % 4 === 0) {
    prev.push([current]);
  } else {
    prev[prev.length - 1].push(current);
  }
  return prev;
}, []);
```

Joseph's iterative approach will be faster though.

Comment: This is great. I like that its still using functional programming. I am not very good with reduce functions but this made perfect sense.

Answer (score 7):

It's not so functional but does the job

```
var splitTest = [];
var length = test.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i+=4){
  splitTest.push(test.slice(i,Math.min(i+4, length)));
}
```

Comment: It looks a lot faster, though. My map function ends up returning an array where 3/4 of the elements are just undefined, which then have to be filtered out. I think its very wasteful relative to this.